# Couldn't find Page with 'id'= // ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PagesController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

i'm starting a little project in Rails, a CMS. And i am having a few problems right here.

class PagesController < ApplicationController
    layout "admin"

```
def index
    @pages = Page.sorted
end

def show
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @page = Page.new({:name => "Default"})
    @subjects = Subject.order('position ASC')
    @page_count = Page.count + 1
end

def create
    @page = Page.new(page_params)

    if @page.save
        flash[:notice] = "Page Created Successfully. "
        redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
        @subjects = Subject.order('position ASC')
        @page_count = Page.count + 1
        render('new')           
    end 
end

def edit
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    @subjects = Subject.order('position ASC')
    @page_count = Page.count
end

def update
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    if @page.update_attributes(page_params)
        flash[:notice] = "Page Updated Successfully. "
        redirect_to(:action => 'show')
    else
        @subjects = Subject.order('position ASC')
        @page_count = Page.count 
        render('edit')          
    end
end


def delete
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
    page = Page.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Page Destroyed Successfully. "
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
end

private 
def page_params
    params.require(:page).permit(:subject_id, :name, :permalink, :position, :visible)
end
```

end

The app error says: "Couldn't find Page with 'id'="  --- "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PagesController#show"

And i am not able to find the error, i am following a tutorial and my code its exactly perfect as the tutorial explains... But i still don't understand why is this happening...

Thanks by hand.

Comment: Are u typing url directly in browser?

Comment: When i try to update a page, kicks me out with that error. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Yes, i am working with my browser normally, with the localhost3000, etc etc etc.   And typing every URL , like /pages /sections etc.

Comment: Then may be your giving Id which doesn't exits. Try out with path helpers.

Comment: Nononono... i am typing just the name of the controllers to go there. 
The CRUD is already running and he's in charge of all the process... But, i am having that problem when i try to update a page.

Comment: Could you share your `config/routes.rb` and also the URL visited, is it like: 'localhost:3000/pages/1'?

Comment: How can i upload the complete routes file? , i'm new here.

Comment: Are u using resources :pages in routes.rb?

Comment: My unique active lines at routs.rb are : 
Rails.application.routes.draw do

match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]


root 's_pages#index'


end

Comment: Run rake routes in your cmd prompt. And share that.